# Add a control to WordPress Customize Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

is there a way to add a new control to the "Menu" tab on the customize page?

[picture to menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShCpP.png)

I want a button right over "Menu Locations". 
I've already try to use a add_control function like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( 
        $wp_customize,
        'test', 
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Test', 'yespizza' ), 
            'section' => 'nav_menus',
            'settings' => 'test_setting', 
            'priority' => 10,
        ) 
    ));
```

I don't know how i can get the right section name for the menu.
regards